# Is any completely continuous operator in Hilbert space an operator with an infinite dimensional image?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A$  be  an operator in Hilbert space, and let the elements in H be composed of an orthonormal system of eigenvectors $\phi_n$. Then any completely continuous operator satisfies the notion $$\lim_{n\longrightarrow \infty}\lambda_n=0$$.

And we have also that $$Ax=\sum \lambda_n c_n \phi_n$$

Would then this imply that, if H is infinite dimensional, then the image of $Ax$ is infinite too?

Thanks

Comment: Take for example the identity operator $I$.

Comment: A completely continuous operator on Hilbert space may not have eigenvalues. Unless it is symmetric, or more generally normal.

Comment: The range of $A$ can easily be finite dimensional if only finitely many eigenvalues are different from $0$. These finite rank operators are dense in the compact operators.